# Ajuda no codigo java (Iniciante)

Tags: java

Escrevi esse código em java, para estudar. (Estou aprendendo),porem quando eu tento criar um novo objeto da erro.

Class Empresa :

```
class Empresa {
  String nome = "";
  String cnpj = "";
  int numeroDeFuncionario = 1;
  Funcionario[] funcionario = new Funcionario[numeroDeFuncionario];
```

Porem tenho que criar um "funcionario[i] = new Funcionario" ?

tentei usar :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numeroDeFuncionario; i++) {
  this.funcionario [0] = new Funcionario();
}
```

Codigo Completo:

Classe Funcionario:

```
class Funcionario {
  String nome = "";
  String departamento = "";
  double salario = 0;
  Data dataDeEntrada = new Data();
  String rg = "";

  void recebeAumento(double aumento) {
    System.out.println("O salario atual e: "+this.salario);
    this.salario += aumento;
    System.out.println("O novo salario e: "+this.salario);
  }

  void calculaGanhoAnual() {
    System.out.println("O salario anual e: "+12*this.salario);
  }

  void mostra() {
    //escreve todos os parametros de Funcionario
    System.out.println("Nome e : "+this.nome);
    System.out.println("Departamento e : "+ this.departamento);
    System.out.println("Salario e : R$"+this.salario);
    System.out.println("Ganho anual de : R$"+this.salario*12);
    this.dataDeEntrada.getData();
    System.out.println("Rg e : "+this.rg);
  }

}
```

Classe Data:

```
class Data {
  int dia = 01;
  int mes = 01;
  int ano = 1900;

  void peencheData (int dia,int mes,int ano){
    this.dia = dia;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.ano = ano;
  }

  void getData() {
    String data = dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;
    System.out.println("Data de Entrada e : "+data);
  }



}
```

Classe Empresa:

```
class Empresa {
  String nome = "";
  String cnpj = "";
  int numeroDeFuncionario = 1;
  Funcionario[] funcionario = new Funcionario[numeroDeFuncionario];

//   if (this.funcionario == null) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= numeroDeFuncionario; i++) {
      this.funcionario [0] = new Funcionario();
  }
//
// }


//   void adicionarFuncionario() {}
//
}

class TestaFuncionario{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Funcionario f1 = new Funcionario();

    Empresa emp1 = new Empresa();

    System.out.println(emp1.funcionario);
    System.out.println(emp1.funcionario[0]);

    emp1.funcionario[0] = new Funcionario();


    // f1.nome = "Hugo";
    // f1.salario = 100;
    // f1.recebeAumento(50);
    //
    // f1.calculaGanhoAnual();
    //
    // f1.mostra();
    // System.out.println("\n\n");

    // Funcionario f2 = new Funcionario();
    // f2.nome = "Hugo";
    // f2.salario = 100;
    // f2.recebeAumento(50);
    // f2.mostra();

    // Funcionario f2 = f1;
    //
    // if (f1 == f2) {
    //   System.out.println("Iguais");
    // } else {
    //     System.out.println("Diferentes");
    //   }
  }

}
```

Comment: `this.funcionario[i] = new Funcionario();`

Comment: `this.funcionario [0] = new Funcionario();` dentro do `for` ele vai instanciar várias vezes a posição inicial e não inicializa o resto

Comment: Sua duvida é porque você que precisa criar os objetos dentro do array `funcionarios[]` usando laço ao invés desses objetos serem criados junto com o array?

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso que o problema deve estar sendo indicado **no fim** dessa linha

```
Funcionario[] funcionario = new Funcionario[numeroDeFuncionario];
```

O real problema é a linha seguinte - para esclarecer vou repetir a parte em questão (algumas linhas apagadas):

```
// parte para mostrar o erro - não é a solução
class Empresa {
    ...
    Funcionario[] funcionario = new Funcionario[numeroDeFuncionario];

    for (int i = 0; i <= numeroDeFuncionario; i++) {
```

Aqui fica claro que o comando `for` está diretamente dentro da classe, fora de um método ou construtor. Em Java os comandos de execução (não os de declaração) devem vir dentro de um método, construtor ou bloco de inicialização.

Esse código deve

**ou** ir em um método que deve ser chamado em outro lugar:

```
class Empresa {
    ...
    Funcionario[] funcionario = new Funcionario[numeroDeFuncionario];

    void inicializar() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= numeroDeFuncionario; i++) {
            ...
    }
```

**ou** no construtor que é executado quando a instância for criada (`new Empresa()`):

```
class Empresa {
    ...
    Funcionario[] funcionario = new Funcionario[numeroDeFuncionario];

    Empresa() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= numeroDeFuncionario; i++) {
            ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vi a pergunta e penso que ninguém reparou que não existiam construtores para a classe Funcionario. Getters e Setters também são úteis e boas práticas para assignar o valor de variáveis fora da classe. Por isso criei o código seguinte para testar de maneira simples o que precisas. Usei listas, porque é o recomendado para tratamento de vários objetos do mesmo tipo. Espero ter ajudado.

```
    package empresa.funcionario;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Funcionario {
    //dados
    String nome;
    String departamento;
    double salario;
    String rg;
    int numero;
    //construtor por defeito
    Funcionario() {
    }
    //construtor com parametros
    Funcionario(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    //getters e setters
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }
    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }
    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }
    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }
    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }
    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }
    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    void recebeAumento(double aumento) {
        System.out.println("O salario atual e: " + this.salario);
        this.salario += aumento;
        System.out.println("O novo salario e: " + this.salario);
    }

    void calculaGanhoAnual() {
        System.out.println("O salario anual e: " + 12 * this.salario);
    }

    void mostra() {
        // escreve todos os parametros de Funcionario
        System.out.println("Nome e : " + this.nome);
        System.out.println("numero e :" + this.numero);
        System.out.println("Departamento e : " + this.departamento);
        System.out.println("Salario e : R$" + this.salario);
        System.out.println("Ganho anual de : R$" + this.salario * 12);
        System.out.println("Rg e : " + this.rg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //inicalizar lista de funcionarios vazia
        List<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
        //preencher funcionarios
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            funcionarios.add(new Funcionario(i));
        }
        //mostrar lista de funcionarios
        for (int i = 0; i < funcionarios.size(); i++) {
            funcionarios.get(i).mostra();
        }
    }

}
```